# Limit mongo-connector to a specific collection for Solr indexing

Tags: mongodb, solr, indexing, connector

I am currently attempting to use mongo-connector to automatically feed db updates to Solr. It's working fine through the use of the following command -

```
mongo-connector -m localhost:27017 -t http://localhost:8983/solr -d mongo_connector/doc_managers/solr_doc_manager.py
```

However, it is indexing every collection in my mongodb. I have tried the use of the option -n through the following -

```
mongo-connector -m localhost:27017 -t http://localhost:8983/solr -n feed_scraper_development.articles -d mongo_connector/doc_managers/solr_doc_manager.py
```

This fails with the following error -

```
2014-07-24 22:23:23,053 - INFO - Beginning Mongo Connector
2014-07-24 22:23:23,104 - INFO - Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost
2014-07-24 22:23:23,110 - INFO - Finished 'http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/luke?show=schema&wt=json' (get) with body '' in 0.018 seconds.
2014-07-24 22:23:23,115 - INFO - OplogThread: Initializing oplog thread
2014-07-24 22:23:23,116 - INFO - MongoConnector: Starting connection thread MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
2014-07-24 22:23:23,126 - INFO - Finished 'http://localhost:8983/solr/update/?commit=true' (post) with body 'u'<commit ' in 0.006 seconds.
2014-07-24 22:23:23,129 - INFO - Finished 'http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=%2A%3A%2A&sort=_ts+desc&rows=1&wt=json' (get) with body '' in 0.003 seconds.
2014-07-24 22:23:23,337 - INFO - Finished 'http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=_ts%3A+%5B6038164010275176560+TO+6038164010275176560%5D&rows=100000000&wt=json' (get) with body '' in 0.207 seconds.
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 808, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/mongo_connector/oplog_manager.py", line 141, in run
    cursor = self.init_cursor()
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/mongo_connector/oplog_manager.py", line 582, in init_cursor
    cursor = self.get_oplog_cursor(timestamp)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/mongo_connector/oplog_manager.py", line 361, in get_oplog_cursor
    timestamp = self.rollback()
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/mongo_connector/oplog_manager.py", line 664, in rollback
    if doc['ns'] in rollback_set:
KeyError: 'ns'
```

Any help or clues would be greatly appreciated!

Extra information: Solr 4.9.0 | MongoDB 2.6.3 | mongo-connector 1.2.1

Comment: May i know, in which document did you find -n option?

Answer (score 1):

It works as advertised after deleting all the indexes in the data folder, restarting solr and re-running the command with the -n option.